# Dropping a noun and keeping the adjective in a contrast sentence

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

This sentence is parallel and correct: "Eyes with an average rating of >= 4.0 were included in the attractive cohort, while eyes with an average rating of <=  2.0 were included in the unattractive cohort."

Can this be rewritten more concisely and still be grammatically correct as "Eyes with an average rating of  >= 4.0 were included in the attractive cohort, while those with <= 2.0 were included in the unattractive."

Does this violate parallelism? Is it clear that "those" refers to eyes with average ratings? Is it fine to end the sentence with the adjective unattractive without adding cohort to the end of it?

Comment: *Can this be rewritten more concisely* Yes, and you have done it.

Comment: I would end the condensed sentence with "... were considered unattractive."

Comment: The deleted version sounds at best unattractive to my ears. ' ... those with ≤ 2·0' is the worse offender. // While deleting the second 'cohort' is not an ungrammatical device, the unusualness of the terms here ('unattractive cohort') weighs against a natural-sounding outcome.